# Create new object from variables

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to simplify this expression?

```
const car = { owner: 'john' }
const assets = { house: { owner: 'paul'}, car: car}
```

As the `key` in assets takes the variable name `car`, is it a way to avoid redefining the key name?

Something like this:

```
const assets = { house: { owner: 'paul'}, car}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, but your "something like this" example is valid. You can do it literally, exactly like that.

Comment: [Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Answer (score 0):

All of your two solutions will work.

```js
const assets = { house: { owner: 'paul'}, car: car}
```

... does exactly the same as ...

```js
const assets = { house: { owner: 'paul'}, car}
```

None of these solutions will redefine the variable `car`.

The second solution is called [shorthand property definiton](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions) and works only in ES2015 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works, and it's known as [shorthand property notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions) (ES6):

```js
const car = {
  owner: 'john'
}
const assets = {
  house: {
    owner: 'paul'
  },
  car
};

console.log(assets);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Note that this is different from spreading - shorthand properties will make a new object, spreading (`...`) just directly attach the properties:

```js
const car = {
  owner: 'john'
}
const assets = {
  house: {
    owner: 'paul'
  },
  ...car
};

console.log(assets);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```